# how to create a map with unique keys from a parsed object in javascript es6/2015?

Tags: javascript, json, object, dictionary, ecmascript-6

Lets say I receive a parsed json like below:

`[{"a":1},{"a":2},{"a":3}]`

The keys are the same which is `a`.

How do I make each `a` unique so that the map is usable?'

**EDIT1**:

Results I want:

```
let myMap = {}; //I declare my variable
//Then I fetch a json and parse it
fetch(link)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json(); //parse the json string
    }).then(function(json) {
      myMap = json; //set it to myMap to be used
}
```

For some reason I having duplicate keys although you guys said the json is unique. Do I have to set the json string to `myMap` first and then only parse it?

Comment: How should your output look like ?

Comment: Something like this 
  `{{
    id: 1,
    flight_location: "KUL",
    description: "Kuala Lumpur"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    flight_location: "KIX",
    description: "Osaka-Kansai"
  }}`

Comment: your a is already unique because u have unique values inside 1 , 2 , 3 like that or else create an object id and use dynamic unique id for each objects

Comment: You could keep an index, append it to your "a" and increase it after each use. Alternatively, you could use a random number - depends on how long your json is expected to be since you need to keep in mind the same random number could be generated.

Comment: BTW, you mean [ { a : 1 }, { a : 2 } .. ] or { { a : 1 }, { a : 2 } ..} ??

Comment: [{a:1},{a:2}..] @YourimYi

Comment: could you show us some use case example? cause It's already unique. and if there's some duplication... what do you want? remove? or...

Comment: @YourimYi I want to set a parsed json into a variable (to be read as a map).

Comment: Can you update your question to show you have an array as you answered to Yourim Yi? It will help other readers of this thread/question.

Comment: done edit @PeterBranforn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you can use an [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) as hash table

```js
var data = [{ "a": 1 }, { "a": 2 }, { "a": 3 }],
    object = Object.create(null);

data.forEach(function (el) {
    object[el.a] = el;
});

console.log(object);
```

Or a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
var data = [{ "a": 1 }, { "a": 2 }, { "a": 3 }],
    map = new Map;

data.forEach(function (el) {
    map.set(el.a, el);
});

console.log(map.get(1));
```

The advantage of Map over an Object is, the key can be anything. The key is not converted to string. Maps can have an object or other primitive or not primitive values as key.

Answer (score 5):

Also if you have a single value list or want to make sure it IS unique you can use the index supplied like this:

```
obj.map((item, index) => 
   ...
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
[{a:1},{a:2},{a:3}].map(function(item, index) { item.id = index; return item; });
```

Comment: why map with no return and assingment/later use of array?

Answer (score 0):

Map in javascript doesnot need a unique id, it will iterate through all the value. so it will iterate through all the objects irrespective the fact that the key is same

eg:

```
var kvArray = [{key:1, value:10}, {key:2, value:20}, {key:3, value: 30}]
var reformattedArray = kvArray.map(function(obj){ 
var rObj = {};
  rObj[obj.key] = obj.value;
   return rObj;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `[{a:1},{a:2},{a:3}]` is already unique... but, It's an Array.
so you cannot access an object `{a:2, ...}` directly but find index with looping.

If I understand your question right way... you want to make new MAP with unique key `a` how about this way? - reduce can help us. :)

btw, Nina Scholz's answer is right.

```
let myMap = {}; //I declare my variable
//Then I fetch a json and parse it
fetch(link)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json(); //parse the json string
    }).then(function(json) {
      // myMap = json; //set it to myMap to be used

      myMap = json.reduce(function(p, n) { p[n.a] = n; return p; }, {});
      // n.a or n['a'] - primary key (in sample, [1,2,3...])
      // "myMap[1].foo", "myMap[2].bar"

      // or change KEY as your taste.
      myMap = json.reduce(function(p, n) { p['k' + n.a] = n; return p; }, {});
      // "myMap.k1.foo", "myMap.k2.bar"

      // It's unique but if you want everything...
      myMap = json.reduce(function(p, n) {
        var k = 'k' + n.a;
        if(p[k] !== undefined) { p[k] = n; }
        else if(Array.isArray(p[k])) { p[k].push(n); }
        else { p[k] = [p[k]] ; }
        return p;
      }, {});
}
```